# Delete sections from a list of filenames while maintaining a unique identifier coming after deleted section using Bash Command

Tags: regex, bash, rename, filenames, batch-processing

Thanks in advance to this exceptional community. Please help with my first post ever!
I have been trying to write a command to delete sections of filenames, but cannot figure out how to do so while maintaining the unique identifier that comes after the area I want to delete.

Here examples of the original filenames (I have o folder full of such):

```
101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__01.vsi - macro image - C=0.tif
101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__01.vsi - macro image - C=1.tif
101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__01.vsi - macro image - C=2.tif
101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__02.vsi - C=0.tif
101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__02.vsi - C=1.tif
101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__02.vsi - C=2.tif
```

And the desired result:

```
101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__01- C=0.tif
101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__01- C=1.tif
101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__01- C=2.tif
101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__02- C=0.tif
101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__02- C=1.tif
101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__02- C=2.tif
```

I have been using variations on the following, but have not found a way to conserve the unique C=#.tif at the end of each file.

```
for f in ./*; do mv "$f" "$f%.vsi*C=*.tif}.tif" ; done 
for f in ./*; do mv "$f" "${f%.vsi*}C=*.tif" ; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do two splits by removing the last space separated string and then remove the `.vsi` part

Something like this

```
for f in *.tif; do
    echo mv -v -- "$f" "${f%.vsi*} - ${f##* }"
done
```

Remove the `echo` if you think the output is correct.

This is the output without the `echo`

```
renamed '101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__01.vsi - macro image - C=0.tif' -> '101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__01 - C=0.tif'
renamed '101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__01.vsi - macro image - C=1.tif' -> '101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__01 - C=1.tif'
renamed '101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__01.vsi - macro image - C=2.tif' -> '101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__01 - C=2.tif'
renamed '101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__02.vsi - C=0.tif' -> '101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__02 - C=0.tif'
renamed '101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__02.vsi - C=1.tif' -> '101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__02 - C=1.tif'
renamed '101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__02.vsi - C=2.tif' -> '101 OD_1_20x_L Rho GFP__02 - C=2.tif'
```

Comment: This worked great! The only amendment I found that was critical to its function was to insert a ";" before "done"       for f in *.tif; do mv -v -- "$f" "${f%.vsi*} - ${f##* }" ; done

Comment: In a one-liner yes, you need a comma ';' since it represents a newline which is required.